# How to connect a PCIe device to a chipyard design

Tags: scala, chisel, pci-e, rocket-chip

I'm trying to connect a PCIe device to a chipyard design using the existing `edge` overlay for the VCU118 (slightly modified because I'm using a different board but this should not matter).

[@michael-etzkorn](https://github.com/michael-etzkorn) already posted an [issue](https://github.com/sifive/fpga-shells/issues/165) on Github about this in which they explain how they only got this working using two different clocks.

I'd appreciate it if I could get some pointers as to how this is done (the issue leaves out some implementation details of the configs) and also if it would be possible to do this without adding an extra clock (@michael-etzkorn [points out that this could cause some issues](https://github.com/ucb-bar/chipyard/issues/964#issuecomment-1152972087)).

Comment: "Slightly modified because I'm using a different board but this should not matter"

This could matter. What board? 

Do you mind sharing some of what you've tried so far? The port for the ExtTlMem key shows how you can punch out tilelink ports. You can start with showing what you've done for that for IOBinders / HarnessBinders

Comment: The board is very similar to the VCU118 so really the only difference is that I have to use different pins for the connections with the board. So far I created a trait to add a CTRL port and a new digital top with with `CanHaveSlaveTLPort`,  `CanHaveMasterTLMMIOPort` and the new trait for adding the CTRL port.

Also I'm unsure how to connect each of the nodes exposed by the overlay (master, slave and control).

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/sant0s12/ad08e36c46059d59a64c9eb9ab34dbb9) is what I have done so far. I'd appreciate it if you could help understand some things: 1. How do I know how big of an address range I should reserve for PCIe (master and control)? 2. How do I connect the interrupt node to the system?  I noticed that you left it out in the version you posted on github but I wonder if you figured it out already. Thanks!

Comment: Ah thanks for this, I had typed up an answer based on assuming you had little done beyond the ports. It seems like you're most of the way there. I'll note that the PCIe Overlay is for a Root Complex (not an endpoint), so you'll have to change the XDMA wrapper for that. The interrupt node is only for the root complex.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the work in your gist, it looks like you've answered most of your original question, but since I already typed this out I'll include it as an answer here.

---

To hook up any port, you'll essentially need to do three things.

1. Create an IOBinder
2. Create a HarnessBinder
3. Hook up the diplomatic nodes in the TestHarness

The IOBinder takes the bundles from within the system and punches them through to chiptop. The HarnessBinder connects the IO in ChipTop to the harness. Diplomacy negotiates the parameters for the diplomatic nodes. This step may be optional, but many modules, like the XDMA wrapper in the PCIe overlay, are diplomatic so this is usually a required step.

### IOBinder

The IOBinder can take your `CanHAveMasterTLMMIOPort` and punch out pins for it

```scala
class WithXDMASlaveIOPassthrough extends OverrideIOBinder({
    (system: CanHaveMasterTLMMIOPort) => {
        val io_xdma_slave_pins_temp = IO(DataMirror.internal.chiselTypeClone[HeterogeneousBag[TLBundle]](system.mmio_tl)).suggestName("tl_slave_mmio")
        io_xdma_slave_pins_temp <> system.mmio_tl 
        (Seq(io_xdma_slave_pins_temp), Nil)

    }
})
```

This can look relatively the same for each port. However, I've found experimentally, I had to flip the temp pin connection `<>` for `CanHaveSlaveTLPort`.

### HarnessBinder

The harness binder retrieves that port and connects it to the outer bundle. The `pcieClient` bundle is retrieved from the harness and connected to `ports.head` which is returned from IOBinders. This is essentially a fancy functional programming way to clone the IO and connect it to the bundle in ChipTop.

```scala
class WithPCIeClient extends OverrideHarnessBinder({
    (system: CanHaveMasterTLMMIOPort, th: BaseModule with HasHarnessSignalReferences, ports: Seq[HeterogeneousBag[TLBundle]]) => {
        require(ports.size == 1)
        th match { case vcu118th: XDMAVCU118FPGATestHarnessImp => {
            val bundles = vcu118th.xdmavcu118Outer.pcieClient.out.map(_._1)
            val pcieClientBundle = Wire(new HeterogeneousBag(bundles.map(_.cloneType)))
            // pcieClientBundle <> DontCare 
            bundles.zip(pcieClientBundle).foreach{case (bundle, io) => bundle <> io}
            pcieClientBundle <> ports.head 
        } }
    }
})
```

Also, I should note: this isn't the ideal way to connect to the harness as its possible BundleMap user fields are generated and they won't be driven unless you have that `pcieClientBundle <> DontCare` there. I found I had to expose AXI ports instead and modified the overlay to output axi nodes to get Diplomacy to work between the testharness and ChipTop regions.

A write up of that problem along with some more info at:

[What are these `a.bits.user.amba_prot` signals and why are they only uninitialized conditionally in my HarnessBinder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69167589/what-are-these-a-bits-user-amba-prot-signals-and-why-are-they-only-uninitializ)

All this code is at that question.

### TestHarness Diplomatic Connections

```scala
val overlayOutput = dp(PCIeOverlayKey).last.place(PCIeDesignInput(wrangler=pcieWrangler.node, corePLL=harnessSysPLL)).overlayOutput
val (pcieNode: TLNode, pcieIntNode: IntOutwardNode) = (overlayOutput.pcieNode, overlayOutput.intNode)
val (pcieSlaveTLNode: TLIdentityNode, pcieMasterTLNode: TLAsyncSinkNode) = (pcieNode.inward, pcieNode.outward)

val inParamsMMIOPeriph = topDesign match { case td: ChipTop => 
        td.lazySystem match { case lsys: CanHaveMasterTLMMIOPort => 
              lsys.mmioTLNode.edges.in(0)
        }
    }
 val inParamsControl = topDesign match {case td: ChipTop => 
        td.lazySystem match { case lsys: CanHaveMasterTLCtrlPort => 
            lsys.ctrlTLNode.edges.in(0)
        }
    }

 val pcieClient = TLClientNode(Seq(inParamsMMIOPeriph.master))
 val pcieCtrlClient = TLClientNode(Seq(inParamsControl.master))
 val connectorNode = TLIdentityNode()


 // pcieSlaveTLNode should be driven for both the control slave and the axi bridge slave
 connectorNode := pcieClient 
 connectorNode := pcieCtrlClient 
 pcieSlaveTLNode :=* connectorNode
```

### Clock Groups... (unsolved)

pcieWrangler was my attempt at hooking up the `axi_aclk`. It's not correct. This just creates a second clock with the same 250 MHz frequency as the `axi_aclk` and so it *mostly* works but using a second clock isn't correct.

```scala
    val sysClk2Node = dp(ClockInputOverlayKey).last.place(ClockInputDesignInput()).overlayOutput.node 
    val pciePLL = dp(PLLFactoryKey)()
    pciePLL := sysClk2Node 

    val pcieClock = ClockSinkNode(freqMHz = 250) // Is this the reference clock? 
    val pcieWrangler = LazyModule(new ResetWrangler)
    val pcieGroup = ClockGroup()

    pcieClock := pcieWrangler.node := pcieGroup := pciePLL
```

Perhaps you can experiment and find out how we can hook up the `axi_aclk` as the driver for the axi async logic :)

I'd be happy to open a question about that since I don't know the answer yet myself.

---

To answer some follow up questions

> How do I know how big of an address range I should reserve for PCIe (master and control)?

For control, you can match the size of in the overlay `0x4000000`. For the master port, you'd ideally just hook a DMA engine up to that that has access to the full address range on the host. Otherwise, you have to do AXI2PCIE BAR translation logic to access different regions of host memory which isn't fun.

> 2. How do I connect the interrupt node to the system?

I believe this is only if you're connecting a PCIe Root Complex. If you're connecting a device, you shouldn't need to worry about the interrupt node. If you do wish to add it, you'll have to add the `NExtInterrupts(3)++` to your config. I only got so far as that and my uncommented code in the TestHarness before I realized I didn't need it. If you feel you do, we can open a new question and try answering this more fully.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the detailed answer! This will help me out a lot. So the thing left to do is to modify the XDMA wrapper (thanks for pointing this out, I am quite unfamiliar with how PCIe works). I'll try that out and report back :) Also, if I get the chance I will take a look at the clock situation and see if I can figure something out.

Comment: I think I found a way to connect the clocks the way you want. Instead of creating a new PLL just use the same one connected to the sys_clock like this:
val newWrangler = LazyModule(new ResetWrangler);
newWrangler.node := ClockGroup() := harnessSysPLL. Now you can pass the new wrangler to the PCIe Overlay.